# Maximum self sufficient induced subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I am trying to find an efficient polynomial algorithm to solve the following problem :

For a directed graph $G = (V, E)$ such that every arc $e$ has some capacity $c_e$ and every vertex $v$ has some demand $d_v$. We know that for every vertex $v$, $$\sum_{e\in E : e=(v,w)} c_e \ge d_v.$$ We say that the graph $G$ is self-sufficient

For a fixed vertex $u$. We want to find the maximum set $S$ that does not contain $u$ and such that $G(S) = (S, E\cap \left(S\times S\right))$ is self-sufficient.

My first thought is to try to modelize the problem which I do as follow :

$$
\max_{y\in \{0,1\}^V} \sum_{v\in V} y_v : \sum_{e \in E: e = (v,w)} c_ey_w \ge d_vy_v,\; \forall v\in V;\; y_u = 0.
$$

Where $y$ will be the indicator of the set $S$. The problem that I do not have any idea how to solve this problem efficiently. Does anyone have an idea.

Comment: Can capacities be negative?

Comment: Let's assume that they are nonnegative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the self-sufficiency condition is violated at a vertex $v$ of $G$, it's also violated at $v$ in every subgraph of $G$ that contains $v$.

So if we begin by taking the set $S = V(G) - \{u\}$ and checking $G[S]$ for self-sufficiency, any vertex at which the condition is violated is a vertex we can never use. Remove those from $S$ and repeat.

Eventually we'll reach a self-sufficient $G[S]$ (in the worst case, when $S = \emptyset$). Because we only removed vertices we knew could never be part of a self-sufficient graph, we get the maximum self-sufficient graph.

Comment: This is a good idea. However the time comlexity of it is $O(V \cdot E)$ which a little bit slow for me. Do you think we can do better ?

Comment: You should be able to implement this algorithm in $O(E)$ time. For each edge $vw$, you will need to ask "is $w$ still self-sufficient now that we have deleted $v$?" (or the reverse) at most once. Just begin by computing all the values of $\sum c_e$, and don't recompute them from scratch every time. (And, I guess, only check the condition at a vertex after you've deleted an adjacent vertex.)

Comment: Thank you! This should absolutely work for me.